# Regex for relativepath

Tags: c#, regex

For the below line

`<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\repo\projext\Base\Src\Index\Index.cs">`

1.Have to start the line with `<Compile`

2.if contains `..\..\..\..\repo` need to change it as `..\..\..\`

I have to remove(\..\repo)from above line where repo value will be changed dynamically.

How to achieve this through Regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\.\.\\[^\\.]+
```

Explanation:

- `\.\.\\` - the `..\` part literally (both `.` and `\` should be escaped in regex)
- `[^\\.]+` - any character sequence not containing `\` or '.'

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5c.%5c%5c%5b%5e%5c%5c.%5d%2b&i=%3cCompile+Include%3d%22..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5crepo%5cprojext%5cBase%5cSrc%5cIndex%5cIndex.cs%22%3e)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define capture groups for that purpose. First use this regex

```
(^<Compile.*)(\.{2}\\[^\.\\]+)(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YipU1l/4)

```
var pattern = @"(^<Compile.*)(\.{2}\\[^\.\\]+)(.*)";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1$3");
```

Notice that we're only printing `$1` and `$3`, and omitting `$2` which you don't want.

Comment: need to check following cases

1.it should start with <compile

2.Need to handle this case also(\..\re-po)

Comment: .superb it works as expected..but that line need to  start with <compile

Comment: @JeevaS OK... I've updated answer further. See Edit #3

Comment: It didn't work. i get `project\Base\Src\Index\Index.cs">`only.
`<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\repo` removed entirely